# How to drag and drop label out of the form at coding time in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

I am currently developing a Windows application which requires about 45 labels and 
corresponding textboxes inside a form. When I add about 10 labels the form, the form gets filled and I cannot add anymore labels to the form.

Here's the screenshot:

[image]

What am I supposed to do if I have to add another 10 labels below the last label in the image? The length of the form cannot be increased beyond 780. I am using Visual Studio 15.7.2

Comment: why cant you bunch them up more? theres a huge gap at the top, and huge gaps in between

Comment: i know. i put this image just to explain my situation. i want to add  about 45 labels to a form. please assume that there is no space at the top. i want to know how can i drag a label from Toolbox to beyond the length of the form?

Comment: I guess it doesnt explain then.

Comment: Use copy & paste: select 10 existing labels, copy and paste them

Comment: Set `AutoScroll` to `true`.

Comment: 45 labels and textboxes ! i could think the case where you want to have custom control (lable + textbox), and add that on run time. not compile time

Comment: @eegooDeveloper - Design Time - You can Resize/Stretch the Form. Click on the Form Header you will notice the "mini squares" will appear on the form. Another way I can think of is that you can make forms body as a Scrollable area. That way User can scroll down (at Runtime) to view/use so many labels.

Comment: For so many Labels - Why dont you use PropertiesWindow type of Control.

Comment: A form can't be larger than the (current) screen. So plan how to handle scrolling. - You can use a FlowLayoutPanel instead of dropping them onto the form directly. Always try to insert a suitable container control between form and controls! -

Comment: Put your labels/textboxes in a Panel. Then, you can scroll in that panel and can add as many as you like dynamically